# Send messages to Skype "group" chat from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, skype, skype4com

Is there an easy way to send group chat messages to Skype from .NET?  I don't need to respond to any commands or anything, so it doesn't need to be a BOT.  Basically, I would run this program on a dedicated box with Skype running as a special user and I would have it report certain information to a specific group chat.

I understand there is a Skype COM library.  I have seen examples based on that but I haven't been able to get any traction.

Comment: Considering today's announcement, this sort of thing might well be about to get $8.5billion easier.

Comment: On a serious note, can you give more detail about the problems you've had with Skype4COM? Was it a case of there not being a clear way to send group chat?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [currently available Skype API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) for Windows uses [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28VS.85%29.aspx) to exchange text-based commands for controlling Skype (see the [Public API Reference download](http://developer.skype.com/resources/public_api_ref.zip)). There is a new thing called [SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit) in development but it's a closed beta so I don't know what it will do to enhance the experience.

There appear to have been a few projects here and there that have wrapped the existing public API with some .NET-based calls using C#. These either wrap the basic level messaging system or the COM wrapper, Skype4COM (as you have already seen). A Google search gave me these results that seem to get you started:

- [Controlling Skype with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/skypecontrolapicsharp.aspx)
- [How to do Skype in C#](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=92458)
- [C# Example Project for Skype4COM](http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2006/12/c_example_project_for_skype4co.html)

Based on your experiences, I would look at the first item in this list as it appears to be a directly interacting with the Windows messages (i.e. `WM_COPYDATA`) rather than Skype4COM.

**Sending a chat message to a group**
Assuming you utilise the C# wrappers referenced above, here is a rough idea of the commands you'll need from the public API in order to send a chat message to a group.

The command to start a chat is `CHAT CREATE`. It appears from the documentation that you have to specify each recipient (or target, as the written in the API reference) individually. Whether this can be a group name or not is not made clear, however, the `GET GROUP USERS` command enables you to obtain the individual users within a specific group.

Once you have a chat, you can use the `CHATMESSAGE` command to actually post a message.