# Any better way to send message to some user using skype?

Tags: skype

I want to create a program that occasionally notify me and my partners when certain things happens. Market movements, etc.

The program is simple. When something happen we send a message.

I looked at this

[Send messages to Skype "group" chat from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953643/send-messages-to-skype-group-chat-from-net)

And it seems that it has obsolete answers. The .com skype is discontinued since 2013.

Now it has botbuilder. However, once I got botbuilder, I am pretty much lost. How in the earth this bot builder allow my program to send a simple skype message.

I am not trying to build a bot.

I am trying to let my program to occasionally send some skype message to me.

What should I do?